# Creating a Vertical Pattern By Subtracting A Given (Variable) Cell By Another Constant (Fixed) Cell

Tags: excel

So basically I am trying to create a pattern in excel by subtracting each of the elements in Column D from *just* Cell A2. I need the pattern to *always* subtract the value of the variable column D cell just from cell A2. So I started off setting D2 (after the heading) to (D2-A2). Then I set D3 to (D3-A2). Then I set D4 to (D4-A2). I then highlight these three cells, hoping the pattern was apparent. I click and drag the bottom right corner of the last cell downward, but excel proceeds to give me (D5-A3) for D5, (D6-A4) for D6, (D7-A5) for D7, etc....

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I want to be able to create this pattern for the column, but it's not able to pick up on it when I drag the lower-right corner of the highlighted cells downwards.

Comment: you want to use [absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-DFEC08CD-AE65-4F56-839E-5F0D8D0BACA9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first cell, use `=(D2-A$2)`. The "$" makes it so that Excel does not change this component when copy-pasted.

Comment: If you want to copy-paste to the right or left but still want the formula to refer to A2, be sure to add a "$" before the A (`=(D2-$A$2)`).